# Extracting certain fields from scala object <-> Json

Tags: json, scala, dictionary, jackson

I'm trying to extract certain fields from Scala object before converting to Json. Is there an easy way to do this.

It would also work if i could make a new Json with certain fields from a Json.

Comment: Provide some examples.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply extract out the value of a Json and scala gives you the corresponding map. Example:

```
 var myJson = Json.obj(
          "customerId" -> "xyz",
          "addressId" -> "xyz",
          "firstName" -> "xyz",
          "lastName" -> "xyz",
          "address" -> "xyz"
      )
```

Suppose you have the Json of above type. To convert it into map simply do:

```
var mapFromJson = myJson.value
```

This gives you a map of type : **scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap**

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without more details.  Suppose that you have the following Scala case class...

```
case class SomeObject(customerId: Long, addressId: Long, firstName: String, lastName: String, address: String)
```

...and that you wanted to extract the 'firstName', 'lastName', and address fields and then convert the object to Json.  Using [`play-json`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJson) you could define an implicit conversion on the companion object for the `SomeObject` class...

```
object SomeObject {

  implicit val someObjectWrites = new Writes[SomeObject] {
    def writes(object: SomeObject) = Json.obj(
      "firstName" -> object.firstName,
      "lastName" -> object.lastName,
      "address" -> object.address
    )
  }

}
```

Then you could just use the code as follows:

```
val obj = SomeObject(12345, 678910, "John", "Doe", "My Address")
val json = Json.toJson(obj)
```

Note that there are probably other JSON libraries, besides `play-json`, that support similar functionality.